# Access is denied for remote powershell session from IIS

Tags: powershell, iis, office365api

I am having problems running a powershell script (to connect to Office365 Services via a remote session behind a proxy server) from IIS.

When I run the script locally in VS2015 and Powershell ISE, it works. However when I ran via the deployed site in IIS, I get "Access is denied".

A few details that might help
- The app pool for the site is using my account. Same account I used to ran the script in VS 2015 and Powershell ISE. It works fine. 
- I am authenticating against a proxy server in the script for it to work.

I have tried everything. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
Import-Module SkypeOnlineConnector

# Prepare proxy credentials
$proxySecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $proxyPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$proxyCredential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $proxyUserName, $proxySecurePassword

# Login into proxy
$webclient=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Proxy.Credentials=$proxyCredential

#Set proxy access type
$proxysettings = New-PSSessionOption -ProxyAccessType $proxyAccessType 

# Prepare Office 365  credentials
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $username, $securePassword


#Connect to Sfb Online
$session = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $credential -OverrideAdminDomain "$adminDomain" -SessionOption $proxysettings
Import-PSSession $session

#Get Skype Policies
Get-Csonlineuser -Identity "$upn" | Select ConferencingPolicy, ExternalAccessPolicy

#Remove Session
Remove-PSSession $session
```

Comment: It would certainly help if you would provide the mentioned script.

Comment: I'm not certain of the environment IIS runs the script in, but there are two things to keep in mind: credentials and double-hopping. Credentials are easy, if a script is run by a user it uses their credentials. If you're trying to remote to another computer, you need to either provide credentials or bear in mind what user is running the session. The double-hop problem is when you start a session, then try to connect it to another session. That problem is complex and trickier to work around.

Comment: @Paxzk, I updated the question with the script. I hope this helps! Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the snipped code where you call the script in the IIS site (Or what is the context where the script is invoked) ?